# Get value of a field with Ndepend

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

I'm trying to make a rule for detect fields that hava assigned values with Ndepend. But I don't know if it's possible to get the value of the fields.

For example, if I have String X='abc' I want to retrieve the x value that would be 'abc'

Comment: no, you cannot get field value with NDepend for now